# Show linear operator and ﬁnd null space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^3,Y = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T : X \to Y$ deﬁned by $T (x_1,x_2,x_3) = (2x_2 −x_3,x_1 + 4x_2)$. Show that $T$ is linear operator and ﬁnd the null space of $T$.

I'm stucked at the first part where we need to show $T$ is a linear operator, Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of a linear operator?

Comment: Operator that satisfies linearity

Comment: L(f+g)=L(f)+L(g) ,where f and g are elements of the space E
(L(af))=a(L(f)),where a is a scalar and f is an element of E

Comment: Yes! Then, take $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and verify that $T(f+g) = T(f) + T(g)$ and that $T(af) = aT(f)$ with the expression of $T$ you have.

Comment: Did you manage to use the definition?

Comment: not yet .. still can't seem to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $(u,v)\in (\mathbb{R}^3)^2$. Let $u = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$.

Then, on one hand $T(u+v) = (2(u_2+v_2) - (u_3+v_3) , (u_1+v_1)+4(u_2+v_2) )$

On the other hand, $T(u) = (2u_2 - u_3, u_1 + 4u_2)$ and $T(v) = (2v_2 - v_3, v_1 + 4v_2)$ thus, 
$$
T(u) + T(v) = (2(u_2+v_2) - (u_3+v_3) , (u_1+v_1)+4(u_2+v_2) ) = T(u+v)
$$

The first point is proven.

Now, let $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lambda u = (\lambda u_1, \lambda u_2,\lambda  u_3)$ and:
$$
T(\lambda u) = (2\lambda u_2 - \lambda u_3, \lambda u_1 + 4 \lambda u_2) = \lambda (2u_2 - u_3, u_1 + 4u_2) = \lambda T(u)
$$

And the second point is proven, thus $T$ is indeed a linear operator.